Notation question regarding quotient groups
I have stumbled upon the following question from the book 'Module theory - An approach to linear algebra' by T.S. Blyth. Question 10 in chapter 8 asks the following question:

My question is mainly regarding the notation used for $[M,N]$ which is said to be a corresponding quotient group. A priori I don't see any condition regarding $M$ and $N$ to be submodules of each other. Does anyone have an explanation what do they mean by this symbol?

$[M,N]=Hom(M,N)/P(M,N),$ so there is no need for $M$ to be a subgroup,of $N,$ just $P(M,N)$ to be a subgroup (sub-module) of $Hom(M,N).$

@ThomasAndrews Please avoid answering questions in the comment section. This is not how comments are supposed to be used: they should only clarify the problem, and answers should be posted as answers. See here for more information.

I wasn't sure that was really the heart of the question, although I knew it was what was explicitly asked about. It seemed like OP included all that stuff after the definition for a reason, though I wasn't sure. @MartinBrandenburg

Please do not use images to convey critical mathematical information not otherwise present in your post. Here is why

@ThomasAndrews by the way, is the factor through projectives definition, means that each such  map has a specific projective module which has a commutative diagram, or is it true for all projective maps?

"The corresponding quotient group" comes just after asking you to show that $P(M,N)$ is a sub-group of $\operatorname{Hom}_R(M,N).$ Thus, the question is telling you to define:
$$[M,N]=\operatorname{Hom}_R(M,N)/P(M,N).$$
They could have been clearer, but since there is no subgroup relation mentioned anywhere else, this is the obvious meaning.
They certainly wouldn't be meaning $N/M,$ since we already have notation for that.
